# after() method temporarily freezes tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make the text from a tkinter label change after ten seconds using the after method. but when I run the program, nothing happens for ten seconds and the the GUI appears and the label has the second text, not the first. What I want is for the GUI to appear, and the label to have the first text, ten seconds later the text in label should change to the second text.

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("sistema de registro de peso aromaticas")
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.etiqueta=tk.Label(text="1")
        self.etiqueta.pack()
        def cambio():
            self.after(10000, None)
            self.etiqueta.configure(text="2")
        cambio()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I know I can make it work without using class inheritance but I am making an interface with various windows and I am using different classes for every window. So I need this to work inside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.after(10000, None)` is the same as `self.after(10000)`, which is effectively the same as `time.sleep(10)`. It freezes the UI until the timer period is up.

If you want to call `self.etiqueta.configure(text="2")` then you can do it like this:

```
def cambio():
    self.etiqueta.configure(text="2")
self.after(10000, cambio)
```

That will cause the `cambio` function to run after 10 seconds.

Comment: Or in short `self.after(10000,lambda: self.etiqueta.configure(text="2"))` ?

Comment: thank you Cool Cloud this solved my problem, but with it did not work before? why do I need to put a lambda function ? with this mrthod i cannot call the same function over and over again, like to update the label text every 10 seconds or something like that? I know that this is kind of outside of the original question, but I wanna learn how to use tkinter well.

Comment: @countzero: my answer explains why it did not work before. Calling `after` without a second argument simply freezes the app. You must tell it what function you want to run after the delay.

Comment: @countzero You should follow this answer and then inside the function, put `self.after(10000, cambio)`. This would make it like a _loop_.

Comment: but @BryanOakley, when I do it like you said in your answer, I keep getting the same problem, nothing happens for 10 seconds and then the gui appears with the text on the label saying 2.

Comment: @countzero Just change `self.after(10000, None)` to `self.after(10000, cambio)`.